# XSS - will javascript execute in anchor tag where "/" by default added by server in href

Tags: xss

I came across a scenario, where userinput is reflecting in anchor tag href value. So if i put test there it reflects as `<a href="/test">`
Due to this default slash added in the code, `javascript:alert(1)` will not execute since, it will be treated as URL. Also `"` is not allowed and gives 400. 
In this case, is there a possibility to bypass the check, or any way to XSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of keeping things simple, let's assume that you cannot break out of the `href` attribute and that your input is always prefixed by a `/`. Unfortunately, there is not trivial bypass for this scenario since as you pointed out, the `/` renders your payload harmless.