# Are all anchor tag href attributes considered XSS vulnerabilities?

Tags: xss

I've got an app which allows users to customize the "thank you" message that is displayed to users when a form is submitted.

For the "thank you" message contents I've whitelisted allowable HTML tags and their corresponding attributes. One of the tags that I allow is an anchor tag and it's corresponding `href` attribute, so that users can add links to their "thank you" messages.

I recently received a report from a pen-tester who claims that my thank-you form is susceptible to cross site scripting because it is possible for a user to execute JavaScript from the `href` tag, as such:

```
<a href="javascript:alert()">Is this XSS?</a>
```

Any other attributes are stripped from the anchor tag.

Questions:

1. Is this technically considered XSS?
2. If so, how can I mitigate this "attack"?

From reading [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/133565/xss-will-javascript-execute-in-anchor-tag-where-by-default-added-by-server) it appears that I could require the `href` attribute to start with either an `h` or a `/`. Would that be sufficient?

Answer (score 4):

> Is this technically considered XSS

Absolutely.When the user click's the tag the javascript will get executed in the context of the domain.So it is a legitimate XSS.

> If so, how can I mitigate this "attack"?

OWASP XSS prevention [cheatsheet](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md) is an excellent resource for such questions.

**They state that**

> Do not encode complete or relative URL's with URL encoding! If
>   untrusted input is meant to be placed into href, src or other
>   URL-based attributes, it should be validated to make sure it does not
>   point to an unexpected protocol, especially javascript links. URL's
>   should then be encoded based on the context of display like any other
>   piece of data. For example, user driven URL's in HREF links should be
>   attribute encoded.